# Suggest me 10 or more inch Tablet with removable battery

Tags: android, tablet

I don't know how to search for tablets with removable battery. If I choose tablets in gsmarena search using tablet by features, it doesn't give me option for replaceable battery. Can you suggest me some? Better would be if method how to root it would be discovered and also bootloader unlocking available.

Comment: Interesting question, do you know of any such tablets?
I'd think the tablet form factor infers wide, long but thin batteries, which wouldn't lend themselves well to being easily replacable.

Comment: I saw, I think, max 8 inch tablet with removable battery somewhere. I just hope if there are any 10 or above. I have Lenovo Tab 10 I bought it from man who got it with television service and sold it for me for 85€ new with warranty. In my country (Lithuania) I didn't find who can replace it. On the internet I found replacement kit which costs 60€! Do you think I want to replace battery for 60€ if I bought it for 85€? :D